# How to reset state in aiogram FSM without resetting data

Tags: python, aiogram

I am developing a telegram bot using Python 3.9.7 and aiogram 2.16, at the end of my function I want to reset the user's state **without deleting the stored data**.

I tried using state.finish() but this method removes all saved data from storage
Here's the code:

```
if user_data.get("chosen_groups") == "fired":
    # some code here
    await state.finish()
```

I can set the user to the initial stage using State.state.set(), but this reduces the readability of the code and increases the probability of an error.
How can I set the user to the initial state without deleting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only need to reset the state without loosing data, use await state.reset_state (with_data = False).

You can read about this in [aiogram documentation](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev/dispatcher/storage.html#aiogram.dispatcher.storage.BaseStorage.reset_state)